# for loop condition won't be checked properly

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

Im beginner to C/C++.I have defined a reverse strpbrk function which ignores parenthesis (that is named strrpbrk_outside) for a math parser project. Unfortunately program ignores the condition `ch != bound`.

Can anyone explain what the problem really is?

```
char* strrpbrk_outside(char* current,char* target,char* bound,char opening,char closing){

    for(char* ch = current ; ch != bound ; --ch)
    {
        for(char* trg = target; *trg != '\0'; ++trg)
        {
            if ((*ch) == (*trg))
                return ch;
        }
        if ((*ch) == closing)
        {
            ch = find_opening(ch,bound,opening,closing);
            printf("current becomes %s\n",ch);
            if (ch == bound)
                printf("current == bound\n");
        }
    }
    for(char* trg = target; *trg != '\0'; ++trg)
    {
        if ((*bound) == (*trg))
            return bound;
    }
    return nullptr;
}
```

I've tested `find_opening` function and there wasn't any problem.

```
char* find_opening(char* current,char* bound,char opening,char closing){
    int n = 0;
    int i = 0;
    if (*current == closing)
        --current;//Caution:
    for(; current != bound; --current)
    {
        if (*current == closing)
            n = n + 1;
        if (*current == opening)
        {
            i = i + 1;
            if (i > n)
                return current;
        }
    }
    if (*bound == opening)
    {
        i = i + 1;
        if (i > n)
            return current;
    }
    return nullptr;//Caution: returns current and also checks the bound character
};
```

here is my test code:

```
#include <cstdio>
#include <string.h>
#include "AND_OR_NOT.h"

int main()
{
    char str[100] = "!<white1>|<white2>&(<sites>|<words>)";
    char str1[100] = "(!<white1>|<white2>)&(<sites>|<words>)";
    char* pch1 = str1 + 20;
    printf("%s\n",pch1-1);--pch1;
    char* prev = strrpbrk_outside(pch1,"&|",str1,'(',')');
    printf("%s\n",prev);

    char END;
    printf("press any key to end");
    scanf("%c",&END);
}
```

and here is the strange result::

```
)&(<sites>|<words>)
current becomes (!<white1>|<white2>)&(<sites>|<words>)
current == bound
current becomes (_,
current becomes²"
current becomes (1'w
current becomes (
current becomes (µ"
current becomes (1'w
current becomes (1'w
current becomes (1'w
press any key to end
```

[cmd image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ywEet.png)

Comment: Firstly, start by reading the description of the "c" and "c++" tags, they are mutually exclusive in general. Make up your mind and [edit] your question to fix that. Also, reduce your code to a [mcve], which shouldn't exceed a single file that can be compiled and ran without changes. Further, as a new user here, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: In C++ you should use `std::string` rather than C-style strings, _especially_ if you are new.

Comment: Probably you want `*ch != *bound` (comparing values)?

Comment: `ch != bound` compares pointers. If you want to compare strings, use `strcmp` and if you want to compare a singe character, you must dereference the pointer, `*ch != *bound`